# Is it possible to generate entities with automatic annotation

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I would like to generate entities from DB with @ApiResource applied on each entity, is that possible ?

Comment: I suppose it's not unless you write a wrapper for the command that generates the entities

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [Maker Bundle](https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle), you can add an `--api-resource` flag for the `make:entity` command (See [this merge request](https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/pull/178))

Comment: I've actually tried, for this and to generate getters and setters for my entities, but i've an error as the following : `Cannot rename "/srv/api/src/Entity2/Act.phpKmHkpp" to "/srv/api/src/Entity2
  /Act.php".`

Comment: Seems like an issue with file permissions. Is it the complete error message ? Do you see anything in the logs (`var/logs/dev.log`)?